# Google Maps WebView on Android pinch-to-zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, webview, android-webview

I am using the WebView component to display the Google Maps and the [JavaScript API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) for interacting with the map.

The only way to zoom the map I have found on Android are zoom controls(+/-) generated into map by the Google Maps service. The pinch-to-zoom ([See there](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aPinch_zoom.png)) is not working either in embedded WebView or in the built-in stand-alone web browser when I go to the maps.google.com web pages. Interesting is that pinch-to-zoom works on other web pages...

Is this kind of Google restriction? Does it depend on the Android OS version?

Comment: Check this out:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2252

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is because the older android browsers don't allow multitouch events to the javascript runtime. Hence, the API shows the zoom controls as the multitouch events won't be recognized.

Refer 
[google Issue tracked here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11909)

I have tried the same on Android 4.1 JellyBean and it works fine there (allowing multi touch events. Think Google may have fixed this :) )